# Remove specified non-numeric rows

Tags: code-golf, array

<sub>In case there's any doubt: `Nan = Non-numeric datatype` for the purposes of this challenge.</sub>

---

Write a program or function that takes a matrix / array as input, as well as a list of column indices.

The challenge is to remove the rows where all elements in the specified columns are `Nan`. It doesn't matter if other elements in the row are numeric or not. The following examples will hopefully make this more clear (it's one-indexed):

```
Input array:
    16   NaN     3    13
     5    11   NaN     8
   NaN     7   NaN    12
     4    14   -15     1

Input column index: [1 3]

Output array:
16   NaN     3    13
 5    11   NaN     8
 4    14   -15     1

----

Input array:
    16   NaN     3    13
     5    11   NaN     8
   NaN     7   NaN    12
     4    14   -15     1

Input column index: 3

Output array =
    16   NaN     3    13
     4    14   -15     1

----

Input array:
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

Input column index: 1 2 4

Output array:
 []
```

**Rules and clarifications:**

- The matrix will always be non-empty
- The numeric values will be finite, but not necessarily integers or positive values
- The column index vector can be empty (in which case no rows will be removed)
- The column index will never have values exceeding the matrix dimensions
- You can assume there won't be duplicates in the column index list
- You can choose if you want to use zero- or one-indexed values (please specify)
- You can take the input on any convenient format

  - Array as list of lists is OK. The column indices can be separate arguments
- `ans =` and similar is accepted in output
- You are free to choose what type of non-numeric datatype you want to use

  - It should be impossible to perform arithmetic operations with this datatype, or convert it to a finite number using functions such as `float(x)`.

This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes win.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>16</s> <s>19</s> <s>10</s> <s>9</s> <s>7</s> 10 Bytes

Column indices start at zero. Input is a list of lists. Uses an empty string as non-numeric value. Takes list of column indices on the first line and the Matrix with the values on the second line.

```
?Qf-QxkTEE
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3FQf-QxkTEE&input=%5B0%2C2%5D%0A%5B%5B16%2C+%22%22%2C+3%2C+13%5D%2C%5B5%2C11%2C%22%22%2C8%2C8%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2C7%2C%22%22%2C12%5D%2C%5B4%2C14%2C-15%2C1%5D%5D%0A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C2%5D%0A%5B%5B16%2C+%22%22%2C+3%2C+13%5D%2C%5B5%2C11%2C%22%22%2C8%2C8%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2C7%2C%22%22%2C12%5D%5D%0A%5B%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C%22%22%2C%22%22%5D%2C%5B4%2C%22%22%2C6%5D%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C%22%22%2C%22%22%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C%22%22%5D%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C%22%22%2C%22%22%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C%22%22%5D%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

### Explanation

```
?Qf-QxkTEE       # Implicit: Q=column indices, E=Matrix

?Q       E       # If column list is empty no rows get removed
  f     E        # filter the given matrix by each row T
     xkT         # Get the indices of all occurences of an emtpy string (k) 
   -Q            # If the indices match with the given column indices, remove the row
```

**Update:** My first solution handled an empty list of column indices wrong. Fixed it (pretty ugly) at the cost of 3 Bytes. Gonna try to do it better after work...

**Update 2:** Golfed it down to <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes, with some help from @FryAmTheEggman an by improving the algorithm significantly.

**Update3:** Fixed a bug @ThomasKwa discovered. His proposed 7-byte solution did not handle empty column indices right, so I just catch that case with a ternary here. I don't see how I can shorten this atm.

Comment: You can replace `J` with `vz` and `K` with `Q`. `z` is initialized to input, `Q` to evaluated input.

Comment: @Pietu1998 Thanks a lot! :) I knew I was missing something in that regard. Sadly I found a bug when I looked at it again to implement your suggestion which overall increases my byte count until I find a nicer solution.

Comment: `?KEfnmklKm@TdKQQ` empty lists are falsy in Pyth, and assignment statements return the value that was assigned, which saves some bytes. I hope you enjoy golfing Pyth! :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks for the suggestions. Is not really relevant anymore since I improved the algorithm a lot, but I really appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Very nice :) you can save another byte using `L` -> `fnks@LTQE`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I knew about `M` but did not about `L`. Thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: Oh, actually you can use `x` to save some bytes by getting the indices of the empty string and comparing it to the input: `fnQxkTE`. Also, there are a bunch more things like `L`, just FYI: `#BFRI` at least (I'm probably forgetting some) all have different functional modes! :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Awesome, thanks! :) Gotta get used to all the shortcuts, but its just so many ^^

Comment: Doesn't this fail [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fnQxkTE&input=%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C%22%22%2C%22%22%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C%22%22%5D%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)? You should be using `f-QxkTE`.

Comment: @ThomasKwa You are right, thank you! :)

Comment: `e.Q` -> `E` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks! :) Don't know how I missed that...

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```js
(a,l)=>a.filter(r=>l.some(c=>r[a=0,c]<1/0)||a)
```

### Explanation

Expects an array of rows as arrays, and an array of 0-indexed numbers for the columns to check. Returns an array of arrays.

Straight-forward `filter` and `some`. Checks for `NaN` by using `n < Infinity` (`true` for finite numbers, `false` for `NaN`s).

```js
var solution =

(a,l)=>
  a.filter(r=>     // for each row r
    l.some(c=>     // for each column to check c
      r[a=0,       // set a to false so we know the some was executed
        c]<1/0     // if any are not NaN, do not remove the row
    )
    ||a            // default to a because if l is of length 0, some returns false but
  )                //     we must return true
```

```html
<textarea id="matrix" rows="5" cols="40">16 NaN 3 13
5 11 NaN 8
NaN 7 NaN 12
4 14 -15 1</textarea><br />
<input type="text" id="columns" value="0 2" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(matrix.value.split('\n').map(l=>l.split(' ').map(n=>+n)),(columns.value.match(/\d+/g)||[]).map(n=>+n)).join('\n')">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Nice handling of that edge case!

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 18 bytes

```
{{1$\f=_!\se|},\;}
```

An unnamed block (function) expecting the matrix and the zero-based column indices on the stack (the matrix on top), which leaves the filtered matrix on the stack. I'm using the empty array `""` as the non-numeric value.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B0%202%5D%20%5B%5B16%20L%203%2013%5D%5B%205%2011%20L%208%5D%5B%20L%207%20L%2012%5D%5B%204%2014%2015%201%5D%5D%0A%0A%7B%7B1%24%5Cf%3D_!%5Cse%7C%7D%2C%5C%3B%7D~%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aed)

#### Explanation

```
{     e# Filter the matrix rows based on the result of this block...
  1$  e#   Copy the column indices.
  \f= e#   Map them to the corresponding cell in the current row.
  _!  e#   Duplicate, logical NOT. Gives 1 for empty column list, 0 otherwise.
  \s  e#   Convert other copy to string. If the array contained only empty arrays, this 
      e#   will be an empty string which is falsy. Otherwise it will contain the numbers 
      e#   that were left after filtering, so it's non-empty and truthy.
  e|  e#   Logical OR.
},
\;    e# Discard the column indices.
```

Comment: Am I testing it wrong or does this violate the rule about no given column indices? `The column index vector can be empty (in which case no rows will be removed)`

Comment: @DenkerAffe Damn, fixed at the cost of 5 bytes...

Comment: I was there too...You still one byte ahead of me tho, so my plan did not work out yet :P

Comment: "the empty array `""`" Did you mean "the empty string"?

Comment: @ETHproductions There is no difference in CJam. Strings are just arrays of characters, so `[]` and `""` are identical and the canonical representation is `""` (e.g. it's what you get when you stringify an empty array).

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: @ETHproductions demo: http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B1%5Dp%0A%221%22p%0A%5B%5Dp%0A%22%22p

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 19 bytes

```
{⍵⌿⍨∨/⍬∘≡¨0↑¨⍵[;⍺]}
```

The left argument should be a list of indices (and it must be a list, not a scalar), the right argument is the matrix. APL has two datatypes, numbers and characters, so this filters out the character types.

Tests:

```
      m1 m2
   16  NaN    3  13   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
    5   11  NaN   8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
  NaN    7  NaN  12   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
    4   14  ¯15   1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
      1 3 {⍵⌿⍨∨/⍬∘≡¨0↑¨⍵[;⍺]} m1
16  NaN    3  13
 5   11  NaN   8
 4   14  ¯15   1
      (,3) {⍵⌿⍨∨/⍬∘≡¨0↑¨⍵[;⍺]} m1
16  NaN    3 13
 4   14  ¯15  1
      1 2 4 {⍵⌿⍨∨/⍬∘≡¨0↑¨⍵[;⍺]} m2 ⍝ this shows nothing
      ⍴1 2 4 {⍵⌿⍨∨/⍬∘≡¨0↑¨⍵[;⍺]} m2 ⍝ the nothing is in fact a 0-by-4 matrix
0 4
```

Explanation:

- `⍵[;⍺]`: select the given columns from the matrix
- `0↑¨`: take the first `0` elements from the start of each item
- `⍬∘≡¨`: compare to the numerical empty list
- `∨/`: see in which of the rows at least one item matches
- `⍵⌿⍨`: select those rows from the matrix

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <s>32</s> 28 bytes

I'll answer my own question for once. The best I can do in MATLAB is 28 bytes. <s>I was hoping to avoid using both `all` and `isnan` somehow, but haven't found a way yet.</s>

```
@(A,c)A(any(A(:,c)<inf,2),:)
```

Test:

```
A =
    35     1   NaN   NaN   NaN    24
     3    32   NaN    21    23    25
    31   NaN   NaN   NaN    27    20
   NaN    28   NaN    17   NaN    15
    30     5   NaN    12    14   NaN
     4    36   NaN    13    18    11

f(A,[3,5])
ans =
     3    32   NaN    21    23    25
    31   NaN   NaN   NaN    27    20
    30     5   NaN    12    14   NaN
     4    36   NaN    13    18    11
```

This is an unnamed anonymous function that takes the input matrix as the first input variable, and a list of column indices as the second.

In MATLAB, `NaN < Inf` evaluates to false. It can be assumed that all values are finite, thus checking if values are less than `inf` is equivalent to checking if they are non-numeric. `any(...,2)` checks if there are any true values along the second dimension (rows). If that's the case, then those rows will be returned.

**Old version:**

```
@(A,c)A(~all(isnan(A(:,c)),2),:)
```

`isnan(A(:,c))` returns an array with booleans for the specified columns. `~all(isnan(A(:,c)),2)` checks if all values along the second dimension (rows) are non-numeric, and negates it. This results in a boolean vector with ones in the positions we want to keep. `A(~all(isnan(A(:,c)),2),:)` uses logical indexing to extract the entire rows for `A`.

---

The following 24 byte solution would work if the values were guaranteed to be non-zero:

```
@(A,c)A(any(A(:,c),2),:)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 48 bytes

```ruby
->a,c{a.select{|r|c.map{|i|Fixnum===r[i]}.any?}}
```

Input is 0-based indices<sup>1</sup>.

Fairly self-explanatory, actually. `select` elements from the array where `any?` of the indices `map`ped over the row are `Fixnum`s.

Sample run:

```ruby
irb(main):010:0> (->a,c{a.select{|r|c.map{|i|Fixnum===r[i]}.any?}})[[[16,'',3,13],[5,11,'',8],['',7,'',12],[4,14,-15,1]],[0,2]]
=> [[16, "", 3, 13], [5, 11, "", 8], [4, 14, -15, 1]]
```

---

<sup>1: I *finally* spelled this word correctly on the first try! \o/</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 15 <s>16</s> bytes

```
tiZ)tn?ZN!XA~Y)
```

`NaN` is represented in the input as `N`. Indexing is 1-based. For example, in the first test case the input is

```
[16 N 3 13; 5 11 N 8; N 7 N 12; 4 14 -15 1]
[1 3]
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dGlaKXRuP1pOIVhBflkp&input=WzE2IE4gMyAxMzsgNSAxMSBOIDg7IE4gNyBOIDEyOyA0IDE0IC0xNSAxXQpbMSAzXQ)

#### Explanation

```
t       % implicitly input matrix, M. Duplicate
i       % input vector specifying columns
Z)      % matrix N containing those columns of M
tn?     % duplicate matrix N. If non-empty ...
  ZN    %   true for NaN values in matrix N
  !     %   transpose
  XA    %   "all" within each column: gives true for rows of N that contained all NaN's
  ~     %   logical negate
  Y)    %   apply this logical index as a row index into the copy of M that was left
        %   at the bottom of the stack
        % ... implicitly end if
        % implictly display stack contents. If the input vector was empty, the stack
        % contains the original matrix M and an empty matrix. The latter produces no
        % displayed output. If the input vector was non-empty, the stack contains the
        % resulting matrix N
```

Answer (score 2):

## K5, 15 bytes

This uses 0-indexed columns and K's natural list-of-lists matrix representation:

```
{x@&~&/'^x[;y]}
```

Index into the matrix (`x@`) the rows where (`&`) not all of each (`~&/'`) is null (`^`).

In action:

```
  m: (16 0N 3 13;5 11 0N 8;0N 7 0N 12;4 14 -15 1);
  f: {x@&~&/'^x[;y]};

  f[m;0 2]
(16 0N 3 13
 5 11 0N 8
 4 14 -15 1)

  f[m;2]
(16 0N 3 13
 4 14 -15 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 49 bytes

```
function(m,j)m[!!rowSums(!is.nan(m[,j,drop=F])),]
```

Input is 1-based. The function takes a matrix (`m`) and a vector of column indices (`j`) which may be missing.

Two test cases:

```
> f <- function(m,j)m[!!rowSums(!is.nan(m[,j,drop=F])),]
> f(m)   
      V1  V2  V3 V4
[1,]  16 NaN   3 13
[2,]   5  11 NaN  8
[3,] NaN   7 NaN 12
[4,]   4  14 -15  1

> f(m, c(1,3))
     V1  V2  V3 V4
[1,] 16 NaN   3 13
[2,]  5  11 NaN  8
[3,]  4  14 -15  1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 148 Bytes

A function that takes a matrix and an array as input, and output a matrix with the corresponding rows at `nil`. As arrays are quite the same as C's arrays, nihilating is like `free()`ing it as the garbage collector isn't far away.

Arrays are 1-indexed in Lua, and I use the string `"NaN"` as a non-nomber element.

```lua
function f(m,l)c=1 while(c<#m)do x=0 for j=1,#l do x=x+((type(m[c][l[j]])=="number")and 0 or 1)end m[c]=(x<#l and m[c] or nil)c=c+1 end return m end
```

You can try [Lua online](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo), and copy/paste the following code sample to try this submission:

```lua
-- The function that does the stuff
function f(m,l)
  c=1 
  while(c<#m)
  do 
    x=0 
    for j=1,#l 
    do 
      x=x+((type(m[c][l[j]])=="number")and 0 or 1)
    end
    m[c]=(x<#l and m[c] or nil)
    c=c+1 
   end 
   return m 
end
-- A function to format matrixes into "readable" strings
function printMatrix(matrix,len)
  s="{"
  for v=1,len
  do
    if matrix[v]~=nil
    then
      s=s.."{"..table.concat(matrix[v],",").."}"..(v<len and",\n "or"")
    end
  end
  s=s.."}"
  print(s)
end

nan="NaN"
-- Datas in, indexed as matrices[testCase][row][column]
matrices={{{7,nan,5,3},{5,4,nan,4},{nan,4,nan,9},{5,7,9,8}},
{{16,nan,3,13},{5,11,nan,8},{nan,7,nan,12},{4,14,-15,1}},
{{nan,nan,nan,nan},{nan,nan,nan,nan},{nan,nan,nan,nan},{nan,nan,nan,nan}}}
indexes={{1,3},{3},{1,2,4}}

-- looping so we can test lots of things at once :)
for i=1,#matrices
do
  print("\ninput: "..table.concat(indexes[i]," "))
  printMatrix(matrices[i],4)
  print("output:")
  printMatrix(f(matrices[i],indexes[i]),4)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>52</s> <s>51</s> <s>49</s> 46 bytes

```
Delete[#,Extract[#,{;;,#2}]~Position~{NaN..}]&
```

Input is [matrix as list of lists,vector of columns]

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! :) Please correct your formatting and specify your input format including the indexing of the columns as asked in the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 39 bytes

```
m#[]=m
m#r=[l|l<-m,any(<1/0)$map(l!!)r]
```

This uses 0-based indices. Usage example (I'm using `sqrt(-1)` to create `NaN`s):

```
*Main> [[16,sqrt(-1),3,13], [5,11,sqrt(-1),8], [sqrt(-1),7,sqrt(-1),12], [4,14,-15,1]] # [0,2]
[[16.0,NaN,3.0,13.0],[5.0,11.0,NaN,8.0],[4.0,14.0,-15.0,1.0]]
```

It's just a simple filter as seen in other answers via list comprehension. The special case of an empty index list is caught separately.